# Implement Push Notification in my iOS App with a Drupal backend

Tags: javascript

I building an iOS App whose content is being brought from a Drupal site. It is being built in ionic/AngularJS.

I intend to implement "Push Notification" functionality in my app that whatever notification a user sends through my Drupal site is received on my app.

There is a particular module [Push Notification](https://www.drupal.org/project/push_notifications), made specifically for this and has integration with Services, but I can't seem to figure out how I'll show the Push Notification on my app when it's sent from my Drupal site. Probably some small example?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three module you need to require to accomplish notification one is [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) second is [services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) and [push notification](https://www.drupal.org/project/push_notifications) modules.

On cofiguration of push notifications you need to configure APNS certificate for IOS by put on private folder and set path to configuration.

By services module you need call register and deregister push token services.

By rule module you can set action of send push notification to particular token.

Comment: Thanks vgoradiya, but is there some tutorial or are there any steps somewhere I can follow? Thanks a lot

Comment: Form [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/715415/Sending-Push-Notifications-from-a-Drupal-site) you can find step by step process to send notification.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install the Push notification module in your Drupal site.
configuration for Android:

1) Using Google Cloud Messaging set up your project in google developers console projects.

2) Enable google cloud messaging in your project(created on Google developers console).
[image]

3) And get your project's API Key from API manager.

4) Add that key in the configuration of push notification in Drupal site in Google Cloud Messaging API Key.

5) Then you can send push notifications from your Drupal site to your apps. `[configuration > Web services > Push Notifications > Send Push ]`
(If you have done set up on the ionic app you can view push notifications on the mobile app directly.)

You can refer to this [link](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-send-push-notifications-using-gcm-service/)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, but my App is in iOS. But I can I still do it in the same way?

Comment: No,  you have to use APNS certificate and add that certificate in push notification module in certificate folder. You can use https://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1 this link to generate certificate.